# How to perform click operation on the first div element from several divs with same CSS class name

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd

My HTML code is

```html
<div>
<div class="search-card-wrapper" id="search-record-app:39bfa12b-c811-450f-90e4-b49aba8a0873">
   <div class="search-card">
      <div class="search-card-insert search-card-insert--clickable" role="presentation">
         <div class="search-card-info">
            <div class="search-card-info-start">
               <div class="search-card-title h4 text-gray-500-hover text-primary">
                  <a href="https://domain_name/app:39bfa12b-c811-450f-90e4-b49aba8a0873" target="_self" class="d-flex justify-content-between" style="color: inherit;">
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="search-card-wrapper" id="search-record-app:0dd13858-0cca-4079-b4c5-2dff0d9695a4">
   <div class="search-card">
      <div class="search-card-insert search-card-insert--clickable" role="presentation">         
         <div class="search-card-info">
            <div class="search-card-info-start">
               <div class="search-card-title h4 text-gray-500-hover text-primary">
                  <a href="https://domain_name/app:0dd13858-0cca-4079-b4c5-2dff0d9695a4" target="_self" class="d-flex justify-content-between" style="color: inherit;">
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this I have 2 divs with `class=search-card-wrapper`. I want to click on the first div only. Here is the Cucumber code to perform this operation, but somehow this is not working. I'm seeking for some help on this.

```java
static String SEARCH_CARD_LINKS = "//div[@class='search-card-wrapper']//div//a";
static String SEARCH_CARD_LINKS_ARR = "(//div[@class='search-card-wrapper'])[1]//div//a";

public static Performable selectLocationFromResultsV2() {
    return Task.where("Selecting Location",
        waitWaitingStateEnd(TIME_OUT_TIME_FOR_ELEMENT),
        WaitUntil.the(SEARCH_CARD_LINKS, isPresent()).forNoMoreThan(TIME_OUT_TIME_FOR_ELEMENT*2).seconds(),
        Task.where(actor -> {
            if (WaitForElementVisible(By.xpath(SEARCH_CARD_LINKS), 3)) {
                Click.on(SEARCH_CARD_LINKS_ARR);
              System.out.println("selectLocationFromResultsV2 location........");
            } else {
                showUpLog("First result was not found");
            }
        })
    );
}
```

For this I am getting NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No BaseStepListener has been registered - are you running your test using the Serenity runners?
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:899)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepEventBus.getBaseStepListener(StepEventBus.java:153)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepEventBus.wrapUpCurrentCucumberStep(StepEventBus.java:930)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.finishAnyCucumberSteps(StepInterceptor.java:561)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.notifyOfStepFailure(StepInterceptor.java:555)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.logStepFailure(StepInterceptor.java:477)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:462)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:210)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:197)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:85)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:51)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.AnonymousTask$ByteBuddy$XKIZQZt2.performAs(Unknown Source)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.performTask(Actor.java:274)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.perform(Actor.java:254)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.attemptsTo(Actor.java:195)
    at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.attemptsTo(Actor.java:202)
```

How to get this div captured for click operation? I am using feature files to perform this BDD type test cases.

Comment: Can you add id's to the html elements? This type of selection based on the nth element with a class is very fragile and will break with the next change to the UI

Comment: Despite that is the valid point but its not in scope, anything I have to handle to my cucumber script only.